# Codesmith generator 8.0, VS 2019 right click context menu does not have manage output option for .csp files

Tags: visual-studio-2019, codesmith

We upgraded to CodeSmith 8.0 from 5.2. We are using Visual Studio 2019.
I was able to upgrade the codesmith .cst templates. The right click menu on Visual studio 2019 solution explorer doesn't show Manage outputs, generate output or any of codesmith right click options for .csp files
It shows the right click options in windows explorer for .csp files but not for VS 2019.

See the two screenshots. Do I need to do anything special for the options to show up on VS 2019?

Right click menu from Windows explorer. There are code smith options when I right click on the .csp file
[image]

Visual Studio 2019

[image]

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Just updated to VS2019, and now can't generate our data access layer from VS. However, the CodeSmith Generator standalone still works, it just won't automatically add the files/set file parenting in your project.

Answer (score 2):

I work at CodeSmith Tools.. Microsoft broke the world with VS2019 and we are currently blocked by VSIX changes in VS2019 where Roslyn bin folder dependencies are not being deployed within the VSIX. This makes testing / development even more difficult. Until a fix is out we can't resume development of VS2019 as we can't even debug it :.

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: Not yet, we are still broken with issues logged to Microsoft. It's really hard to debug this in the current state. We may have to take a different approach to how the compiler gets referenced indirectly or fight with not being able to debug it locally and patch the vsix.

Comment: @BlakeNiemyjski: Hi Blake, Any progress on this integration of codesmith 8.0 with VS 2019?

Comment: We are still blocked on it and have publicly commented on Microsofts announcement yesterday of new VS Extension rewrite how they've completely ignored breaking issues like the ones we've reported.

Comment: Generator 8.5 has been released some time ago and it supports VS2022.